# Quiero que MI Band2 se conecte automáticamente la segunda vez que abra la app

Tags: android, bluetooth

El problema es que cada vez que abro la app para sincronizar la pulsera MI BAND 2, tengo que pulsar el botón para dar permisos para emparejar. Me gustaría saber la forma de guardar ese emparejamiento para que la segunda vez no tener que volver a pulsar el botón. Por ejemplo, en la app Mi Fit sólo tienes que autorizarla la primera vez, después se queda emparejada.

Gracias.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BTMIBand2Helper.BLEAction {

public String macSelectedDevice;
Button btn_test,btn_test2,btn_test3;
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
BTMIBand2Helper bthelper = null;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        int i = item.getItemId();

        if (i == R.id.navigation_home) {
            fragment = new MIPulsera().newInstance();
        } else if (i == R.id.navigation_dashboard) {
            fragment = new Explorar().newInstance();
        } else if (i == R.id.navigation_notifications) {
            fragment = new Ajustes().newInstance();
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            replaceFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    btn_test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
    btn_test2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_test2);
    btn_test3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_test3);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        macSelectedDevice = extras.getString("MAC");
    }

    firstReplaceFragment();

    bthelper = new BTMIBand2Helper(MainActivity.this, handler);
    bthelper.addListener(this);
    bthelper.connect(macSelectedDevice);

    btn_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bthelper.RequestAuthentication();
        }
    });
    btn_test2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bthelper.SendTextNotification("Izquierda");
        }
    });

    btn_test3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bthelper.SendTextNotification("Derecha");
        }
    });

}

private void firstReplaceFragment() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,new MIPulsera().newInstance());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

private void replaceFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override

public void onNotification(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){

    UUID alertUUID = characteristic.getUuid();

    if(alertUUID.equals(MIBand2Constants.UUID_BUTTON)){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Touch Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: traduce tu pregunta al español, estas en SO en español;; de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Hola @Salva P estas en stackoverflow en español, podrias publicarlo en stackoverflow.com o traduce tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Saludos.